# FB OpenGraph og:image only showing 3 out of 6 images as thumbnail options

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I have 6 og:image tags in the header.php file of my Wordpress site but Facebook is only pulling 3 of the images when clicking a Like or Share button on my site. This was working fine a few weeks ago, I changed nothing and now only 3 of the 6 images show up as thumbnail options.

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.rockitpro.com

That gives an error that one of the images is not big enough when all images are over 200x200 px in size. I'm thinking this is a bug with Facebook maybe? Any ideas?

Comment: Having the same issue. Found this: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/239522122851150/

Comment: My situation is a little different, it's totally random when all 6 images will show when you share a post on my site.For example, all 6 images came up as thumbnail options on the first post a minute ago when I shared it, then I ran the lint tool just now and the first post shows only 3 thumbnail image options.

I fixed the size error on the lint tool so I don't know what else to do, I guess this a Facebook problem that I can't fix.

Comment: Pretty sure its all related to their "ranking" system. Kinda ridiculous in my opinion